# Простое регулярное выражение для вк

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с строки вида `https://vk.com/habr123` получить habr123 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь не нужны регулярные выражения. Здесь нужно из исходной строки удалить первые 15 символов

Answer (score 4):

```
/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?vk\.com\/([a-zA-Z\d\._-]+)/
```

`https?:\/\/` - это https:// или http://

`(?:www\.)?` - необязательная группа без обратной связи соответствует www.

`(?:m\.)?` - необязательная группа без обратной связи соответствует m.

`([a-zA-Z\d\._-]+)` - результирующая группа с номером 1, состоящая из символов латинского алфавита, цифр, точки, подчеркивания и тире, содержащая минимум 1 символ

Тест https://regex101.com/r/a2ADdh/1

P.S. Контактом не пользуюсь, так что не в курсе где у них там что и как хранится и обзывается.

Answer (score 1):

Ищешь первое место вхождения "/" с конца и удаляешь все, что перед ней, включая "/"